# sqlite3.OperationalError('near "(": syntax error') in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, debugging, google-colaboratory

Observing some odd behavior with SQLite 2.6, where the `ROW_NUMBER()` throws an error only in Google Colab (Python 3.6.9), whereas the code works fine in my local Python 3.6.9 and Python 3.9.1 instances. Can you help me debug this further?

**Code**

```
import sqlite3, sys

try:
    print('Py.version : ' + (sys.version))
    print('sqlite3.version : ' + (sqlite3.version))
    print('sqlite3.sqlite_version : ' + (sqlite3.sqlite_version)+'\n')
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

    conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE team_data(team text, total_goals integer);''')
    conn.commit()

    conn.execute("INSERT INTO team_data VALUES('Real Madrid', 53);")
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO team_data VALUES('Barcelona', 47);")
    conn.commit()

    sql='''
    SELECT 
        team,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( 
            ORDER BY total_goals 
        ) RowNum    
    FROM 
        team_data
    '''
    print('### DB Output ###')
    cursor = conn.execute(sql)

    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
    
except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR : ' + str(e))
finally:
    conn.close()
```

**Output**

1. Google Colab (***ROW_NUMBER() causes SQL to fail***):

```
Py.version : 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) [GCC 8.4.0]
sqlite3.version : 2.6.0
sqlite3.sqlite_version : 3.22.0

### DB Output ###
ERROR : near "(": syntax error
```

2. Local Python 3.6.9 (**Succeeds**):

```
Py.version : 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 14:00:49) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
sqlite3.version : 2.6.0
sqlite3.sqlite_version : 3.33.0

### DB Output ###
('Barcelona', 1)
('Real Madrid', 2)
```

3. Local Python 3.9.1 (**Succeeds**):

```
Py.version : 3.9.1 (default, Dec 11 2020, 09:29:25) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
sqlite3.version : 2.6.0
sqlite3.sqlite_version : 3.33.0

### DB Output ###
('Barcelona', 1)
('Real Madrid', 2)
```

---

*Note: Above SQL and code is simplified for error reproduction purposes only*

Comment: Have you tried removing the space between ROW_NUMBER and ()?

Comment: @AllanWind - Yes, I tried with and without spaces..

Comment: Is sqlite3.sqlite_version the same between the two environments?  I see the package versions are.  Specifically, window functions per documentation was added in 3.25.0.

Comment: Window functions were introduced in version 3.25.0 of SQLite: https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#history. Check the version of SQLite that Google Colab uses by executing `select sqlite_version();`.

Comment: Thank you AllanWind and @forpas ! Seeing the same package version of 2.6 confused me initially...got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in question is a window function and support for that was added in version 3.25.  You can check the library (opposed to package) version with sqlite3.sqlite_version or as @forpas shared with the query `select sqlite_version()`.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to wait for Google Colab to upgrade their sqlite version

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your sqlite version. Use this code.

```py
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/packages
!apt update
!apt install sqlite3
# MENU: Runtime > Restart runtime
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version  # '3.33.0'
```

Comment: Thank you. But its Google Colab whom needs to upgrade their sqlite version

Comment: Colab now uses Ubuntu 18,04 which will never use sqlite 3.33.0. You need to wait till they upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04 which is probably in 2022, I guess.